# Catch errors from rmarkdown::render

Tags: r, r-markdown

R newbie question: I am generating PDFs using rmarkdown from the console (not using rstudio). I have written a simple r script to render the rmarkdown file from the console, it basically looks like this:

```
# my_r_script.R
rmarkdown::render('mydoc.Rmd', output_file = opt$out,
params = list(
   something = opt$something,
   else = opt$else
  )
)
```

In the rmd file bad errors might happen, e.g. some calculations might crash due to the given parameters. Question How can I access those errors in the R script? Or in other words: I want to know if something went wrong in the RMD file how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the rmarkdown::render statement in a try catch function - there is a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r).

You should be able to store the output in a variable for further debugging.